# Custom profile URL or routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

Rails 3.2 app

How do I access (read, show action) a resource with a custom URL?

Typically we would do this (REST):

```
http://localhost/entities/23
```

and this will show the data for Entity with id = 23

How can have it going to the same page when using accessing this way:

```
http://127.0.0.1/directory/[entity-name]
```

Is that something I can code in my routes.rb file?

Note that I want to replace spaces in Entity name with '-' in the URL.

Cheers,

joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is slugged or human-friendly urls.

[Friendly ID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) is a great gem which can help you create slugged urls.